# How to sort table with tables?

Tags: lua

How to sort table in my case by id ?

I have output  table from json file , and yes in my table i have zero values where not table.
Input table to sort like:

```lua
local tbl = {1=0, 2=0, 3={ id='1' }, 4={ id='2' }, 5={ id='3'}, 6=0}
```

and sort func

```lua
    local pos = 1
    local sort = function(data)
        for i = 1 , table.maxn(data) do
            if (data[i-1] != 0) and (data[i] == 0) then -- Find next value
                pos = i
            elseif (data[i] == 0) then
                pos = i
            end
            if (data[i] != 0) and (i > pos) then -- Change value
                if (data[i-1] == 0) and (i > 0) then
                    data[pos] = data[i]
                    data[i] = 0
                    pos = i
                    hasChanged = true
                    print(data[i])
                    sort(data)
                end         
            end
        end
    end
    sort(data)
```

This is fine work in my case but if i want sort with some values i don't know how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`table.sort`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.sort) includes a parameter that you can use to specify how to compare table elements. The following function assumes that zeros have to go at the end, after any tables. It doesn't take invalid data into account. Note that the function must return `false` for equal arguments.

```
local function lessThan(a, b)
  if a == 0 then
    -- a is either equal to b, or it has to go at the end.
    return false
  elseif b == 0 then
    -- b has to go at the end.
    return true
  else
    -- Neither argument is 0.
    return a.id < b.id
  end
end

table.sort(tbl, lessThan)
```

If your table is not a valid sequence, (it contains `nil`s), you can use `pairs` and put the elements into a new table before calling `table.sort`.

```
local array = {}
for _, v in pairs(tbl) do
  table.insert(array, v)
end
table.sort(array, lessThan)
```

Comment: I know about it function , but can it help in my case where i have two tables ? Have you seen my input table ?

Comment: What do you mean by "two tables"? I only see one input table.

Comment: Table in table. And why you checking `elseif b == 0 then` ? Its not return error there `return a.id < b.id` ?

Comment: And table.sort not work when table is not sequentially. It say why i not use table.sort in my case.

Comment: I added some explanation to my answer. The `lessThan` function has to check both `a` and `b` to ensure they're both tables before comparing `id`s.

Comment: Possible check if table was sorted with zero ? Because it  start sort from the very beginning always when i call this function. I need  compare two tables old and sorted or have elegant method?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't really understand what you're saying here. Here are some ideas that might help clarify your question: Explain what you want to do with the zeros. Explain all possible input tables that you have to deal with. Explain exactly what you want the output table to look like. Tell us what you mean by comparing "old" and "sorted" tables.

Comment: So , after i sort table , im going to save her to file. But if sorted table not have changes her anyway saved because i dont check have changes in sorted table or not. And i have question: Its possible add variable `HasChanges = true -- or false` to `lessThan` function ?

Comment: No, `lessThan` can't detect when elements get swapped. Probably the easiest way is to copy the table, sort the copy, then compare the two, item by item. Or you could write your own [sort function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Popular_sorting_algorithms) where you make `hasChanges` a local variable and when it's done, return that variable.